# Google Sheet script for comparing values to catch Duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script

i am looking for assistance creating a script that on form submit checks 2 columns or values for duplicates.

If there is a match for both values then the submission is added to the sheet but an email is generated that a duplicate has been entered.

I have experience with forms emailing results onFormSubmit however not comparing the captured values to ones on the sheet and taking action on that.

I am assuming its going to be an If statement but just have no idea on how to start building it out.

Any help would be great

thank you

Comment: This isn't really that kind of site... i don't think anyone will just plop some code down, and this question is addressed in other places. You really should put something together, show your work and then you're more likely to get help. But basically, you'll want to run the script from a google sheets - its easier to work with, and then compare the new array (row) with the other arrays (rows) in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your in luck.  I just did this today for a project of my own.  The input is just a range string in A1Notation.

```
function foundDupes(a1){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('TradingTimes');
  var rg=sh.getRange(a1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var uA=[];
  var foundDupes=false;
  for(var i=0;i<rg.getHeight();i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<rg.getWidth();j++)
    {
      if(uA.indexOf(new Date(vA[i][j]).valueOf())<0)
      {
        uA.push(new Date(vA[i][j]).valueOf());
      }else{
        foundDupes=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return foundDupes;
}
```

It may not be exactly what you want but the basic idea is that you go through your range of interest asking the question is this value already in uA if not then put it in uA and continue on to the next value in your range and ask the same question.  At some point if you have any duplicates then there will be some values that are already in the uA array and guess what you just found a duplicate.